# Overriding Spring controller mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have such a problem that I work on project where some parts are taken from legacy code which is already in JAR files. There are already some Spring controllers imported from those JAR files. I want to `Override` mapping in those imported controllers by extending those classes and creating/writing new methods. Unfortunately, I can not create new mapping because I don't know how many places old mapping appears and looking threw whole system is not possible. As I want to add some new functionality on the same mapping I tried with excluding old(imported) controller and also excluding configuration file which was importing that old controller using:

```
@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX)
```

Spring came back with problem of duplicated mapping and didn't allow me to deploy application properly.

Is there any option to exclude controller from application or check in which places controller bean is injected into application and override it?

Comment: I don't understand your question yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **exclude** a class or package from Spring **component scanning** as below.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(            
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "org.aaa.bbb.*"),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MyClassToExclude.class) })
```

By this way, you can exclude your **legacy** classes.

Comment: It solves problem.  I also need to admit that if You are making some new controller to override mapping You should not extend the one You want to override.